# Rails 5 include ActiveModel Select Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

https://github.com/emrahyildirim/radgroup/

/App/view_models/forms_model.rb

class FormModel

include ActiveModel::Model

Rails console
FormModel.select(:name) can not use the command.

error
nomethoderr (private method 'select' called for

I am asking for your help.

Comment: `select` isn't a method of ActiveModel. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find an asset with a specific name?  .where might be what you are looking for, i.e.

```
FormModel.where(name: 'name_im_looking_for')
```

this will return an array of assets with matching names. (Edit for Accuracy)

Or, you can use

```
FormModel.find_by(name: 'name_im_looking_for')
```

To return the specific asset.

If you simply want to group all assets by :name, use .group which will return an ActiveRecord relation, upon which you can perform aggregate functions on your data such as .count (if that's what you want).

```
FormModel.group(:name).count
```

This will return an object with :name(s) pointing to their counts, e.g.

```
{Sarah: 2, Bill: 3, Potato: 99}
```

Comment: In fact, it will return an array of assets with matching names.  If he just wants one (the first) occurrence, then `FormModel.find_by(name: 'name_im_looking_for')`

Comment: I radcheck table, using the collection selector, I want to group names in the table radgroupcheck.